# Google Chrome freezing when I open Bookmark Manager

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, bookmarks

I have an issue with Google Chrome freezing whenever I open the Bookmark Manager.  Only that particular tab freezes, and I can still use the other tabs.  No bookmarks appear, and I cannot type in the 'Search bookmarks' field.

This seems to be related with my logged in profile.  If I change profile, it allows me to login.  I've also tried to login with my profile on different computers using Chrome, and it also freezes.

However, I can still add bookmarks from the bookmarks tab.  I just cannot use the Bookmark Manager.  Any ideas what I can do?  Is it possible to somehow export my bookmarks, reset the profile bookmarks (without losing other information like extensions etc), and re-import them?